# Mechanics: if there's a change in power doesn't that mean there is a change in driving force, and thus velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, power

here is the question: a car of mass 1100 kg is moving on a road against a constant force of 1550N resisting the motion.

the car moves along a straight horizontal road at a constant speed of 40m/s.

(a) calculate the power developed by the engine of the car. answer : 62 , 000 W.

(b) given that this power is suddenly decreased by 22, 000 W , find the instantaneous deceleration of the car.

now what my book has done is :

P = Fv

40, 000 = F (40)

F = 1000 N

and then it used resultant force = ma to find the deceleration.

my question is , why is the velocity still taken to be 40 m/s when it has clearly said that there is a deceleration?

Answer (score 2):

The problem uses the term *instantaneous deceleration*, which is the deceleration felt at the moment the power is decreased. At this moment, the car's velocity is still 40 m/s. The drop in power will cause the car to decelerate until it reaches a steady state velocity that balances the new power output with the opposing force. The car's deceleration over time changes as it approaches the steady state, eventually going to zero as the car attains a new constant velocity. This problem only asks about the deceleration at the single moment in time when the power drops, at which point the car's velocity is 40 m/s. We can describe the instantaneous deceleration at the moment the deceleration begins, even though the car's velocity hasn't actually changed yet.

Comment: well i understood some of it, but not all, im studying maths, not physics. could you please explain more what you mean by : ''The drop in power will cause the car to decelerate until it reaches a steady state velocity that balances the new power output with the opposing force.''

Comment: @ilovecupcakes With the original engine power output of 62000W, the force pushing the car forward is perfectly balanced by the 1550N force pushing back, so the car doesn't accelerate and has constant velocity. If the car's power output drops, the opposing force is pushing back harder than the engine can resist, so the car slows down. The power output of the opposing force scales with velocity (P=Fv), so as the car slows down, the power required to resist the force also drops. There will be a new lower speed where the car power equals the opposing force power, resulting in a new constant speed.

Comment: i thought power output was just what the car's engine create. are you telling me that resisting forces also have a power output? i dont get '' . The power output of the opposing force scales with velocity (P=Fv), so as the car slows down, the power required to resist the force also drops.'' thanks for helping btw.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes The car does have some power output, but you can also think of the resisting force having a power output (think of it like a powered winch pulling the car backwards, resisting the engine which is trying to go faster). Any force has the potential to do work, and that work divided by time is the power. When the car decelerates, the net force points backwards and does work in decelerating the car. When the car is moving at a constant velocity, there's no net work, so the car's power output must be opposed must be opposed by an equivalent power (or else the car would speed up).

Comment: i'm completely confused. the resisting force here could be anything. it isn't mentioned that it is friction, if it was friction then as the power (driving force) would decrease, then the force needed to resist the motion would decrease as well, given that Fmax = 1550N but we don't know if it is friction. and you're telling me that a resisting force can also have a power, i haven't learned that. if the driving force decreased along with the resisting force then F = driving force until driving force becomes zero. so, it would always be equal but you're telling me that it will be equal only once?

Comment: tell me if i'm wrong, ok.

Comment: the definition of work is the force x distance moved by application of the force in the direction of the force. here the force is in the opposite direction to the distance moved so can it really have work done and thus power? are you sure about this?

Comment: @ilovecupcakes The resisting force is always 1550N, *regardless of the speed of the car*. When the car outputs 62000W, the force driving the car forward equals the resisting force, so net force is 0 and no work is done (constant speed). When the car only outputs 40000W, the force driving the car forward is less than the force pushing it back, so there is a deceleration. Work must be done to change the car's velocity, and here the work is performed by the resisting force (the engine only pushes forward). In W = Fd, the force can be opposite to the motion, it just needs to be *parallel* to it.

Comment: oh okay, but if the driving force is less than the resisting force shouldn't the car go in the direction of the resisting force?

Comment: @ilovecupcakes The car will *accelerate* in the direction of the net force, which it does - when the engine power drops, the car is still moving forwards, but it's accelerating backwards (it is slowing down).

Comment: oh, okay. thanks for the help. :)